# Deploying datasource.xml on Jboss 7.1

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, datasource, jboss7.x

I am trying to add a datasource xml file, named `oracle-ds.xml`, to my JBoss 7.1 folder so projects that I deploy on that server could use that data source.

As it is explained on [jboss.org](https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2012/02/28/excited-about-jboss-as-71-part-i-deployable-datasources), I need to put that file in the deployments folder.

Which is what I did. But unlike what they said in the link above, I have my Orcale driver jar in my local maven repository. Anyway, maven is able to build the project.

Now when I restart Jboss, it seems like it regards `oracle-ds.xml` as a project (jar) that needs to be deployed, not as an xml setting file...

Here is some of the console output during Jboss' restart:

```
15:58:16,666 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "oracle-ds.xml"
15:58:16,728 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."oracle-ds.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.se
rvice.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."oracle-ds.xml".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "oracle-ds.xml"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_29]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
        at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ParserException: IJ010061: Unexpected element: local-tx-datasource
        at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parseDataSources(DsParser.java:183)
        at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:119)
        at org.jboss.jca.common.metadata.ds.DsParser.parse(DsParser.java:82)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(DsXmlDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:80)
        ... 6 more
```

Why does it happen and what should I do to correct this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying the `oracle-ds.xml` to `standalone\deployments` folder is the correct way to deploy it. Although I would recommend defining the data source in the standalone.xml or in the management console or in CLI instead of a separate xml file.

The issue here is that `oracle-ds.xml` is failing the XSD validation. If you look at the [XSD](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/schema/datasources_1_2.xsd) for the data source xml you will find that there is no `local-tx-datasource` element in the XSD.

To resolve this you will need to make sure your XML file passes the XSD validation. Alternatively you can define the data source in the management console or via CLI to avoid creating it manually and running into these types of issues.

Comment: Thanks, how do I run a validation on my current xml?

Comment: You can use Eclipse XSD validation tool.

Comment: Here's a good example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049882/jboss-7-oracle-datasource-configuration