# How to connect JBoss 7.1.1 Final to Oracle Database?

Tags: database, oracle, jboss, connection

I looked over the Internet but I couldn't find any easy tutorials or docs explaining the problem.

I want to connect my JBoss 7.1.1 Final to Oracle Database. I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition on 64bit Windows.

The question is what should I do to connect my jboss to Oracle DB?

Comment: If you use hibernate you can create a connection there. If not google by the keywords `jboss datasouce oracle`

Comment: I am using mybatis, not hibernate. I also tried googling by the keywords, but I couldn't find anything which could be easily explained. For example, most searching result in tutorials connected with older versions of JBoss...

Comment: [This post](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=350) shows you how to configure your datasource in both way using xml file and using administrative console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer [jboss 7 oracle datasource configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049882/jboss-7-oracle-datasource-configuration)

In short, you have to declare a jboss module for your oracle driver.
Then, you create your datasource in standalone-xxx.xml and add the reference to the driver.

Finally, you can use this datasource in any persistence.xml by using the jndi-name declared in the datasource.

All of this is explained in the url provided.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can create JNDI in Jboss 7.1.1 as below and configure mybatis to use this JNDI. make sure you have oracle driver in `Modules` at `com.oracle.ojdbc` localtion.

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
    <datasources>
     <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/test" pool-name="test" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
          <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testDB</connection-url> 
          <driver>oracle</driver> 
         <pool>
              <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size> 
              <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size> 
              <prefill>false</prefill> 
          </pool>
         <security>
              <user-name>username</user-name> 
              <password>password</password> 
          </security>
         <validation>
              <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match> 
              <background-validation>false</background-validation> 
          </validation>
      </datasource>

     <drivers>
         <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc">
            <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class> 
            <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class> 
          </driver>
      </drivers>
  </datasources>
  </subsystem>
```