# Wildfly JNDI datasource not found

Tags: java, jndi, wildfly

I have an application (war-binary-only) with an embedded jndi resource of `java:jdbc/xyz`

Which I try to express in a xyz-ds.xml file, but cannot find the right syntax.

Wildfly insist on having either `java:/` or `java:/jboss` in the beginning of the jndi name, and neither seems to match..

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/xyz" poolname="xyz" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
   ....
</datasource>
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You might want to check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049882/jboss-7-oracle-datasource-configuration/27364088#27364088

Comment: I did. Didn't do anything about the jndi mapping. I already have the drivers I need.

Comment: If you read properly, you need to use java:jboss/ not java:/jboss :)

Comment: yes, sorry, that was my typo. I did not get that the java:jboss/datasources/ would be the equivalent to java:/jdbc , which @Zhedar explained.

Comment: No problem, I'd still recommend to use web-console as explained in my answer. Your case is a great example of common problems when manually adding datasource. I also explain that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in my Wildfly 8 standalone.xml configuration:
    `jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/xyz"`.

This reflects to
    `<jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/xyz</jta-data-source>`
in persistence.xml though.

It's a bit confusing and feels unintuitive, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration), this is the right way.

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried to move it to java:jboss/datasources/xyz, but I cannot still retrieve it from the code, which only has an java:jdbc/xyz (no leading slash)

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen can't you modifiy the jndi in your persistence.xml?

Comment: I see, I'm not really sure if `java:jdbc/xyz` ever was a correct jndi for JBoss servers, so you may be unlucky at this point.

Comment: @Zhedar I am not seeing any reference to `java:/jdbc` in the documentation you point to.